# Why isn't my mat-table UI updating when I update the data that it's displaying?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a table that is using the data from the array `keyData` I want to press a button and add a row to that data.

From console.logs I can tell that the `keyData` array is having the extra row inserted but this is not reflected in the UI.

Here's the HTML:

```
<mat-tab label="Keys">
  <button mat-fab extended (click)="onAddKey()">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    Add Key
  </button>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="keyData" #keyTable class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Active </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.active}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="key-id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key_id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="checkbox">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="keyColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: keyColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</mat-tab>
```

Here's is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-policies',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule, MatTabsModule, FormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSidenavModule, MatTableModule],
  templateUrl: './policies.component.html',
  styleUrl: './policies.component.scss',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class PoliciesComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatTable) keyTable!: MatTable<any>;

  keyColmuns: string[] = ["active", "key-id", "description"]
  keyData: any = []

  constructor(
    private endpointService: EndpointService,
  ) { }

  onAddKey() {
    const newKeyId = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-10)

    this.endpointService.makeRequest({
      params: {
        key_id: newKeyId,
        policy_id: this.openedRow.policy_id,
      },
      method: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
    },
      "aaaaaaaaaa"
    ).subscribe({
      next: (value: any) => {
        console.log('value', value)
        this.keyData.push({
          active: 1,
          api_set_key: value.result.api_set_key,
          description: "",
          key_id: newKeyId,
        })
        // A new row is being inserted here but this is not displayed in the UI until I refresh the page.
        this.keyTable.renderRows();
        console.log('this.keyData', this.keyData)
      },
      error: err => {
        console.error('Error:', err)
      },
    })

  }
```

I have also tried running `detectChanges();` from `ChangeDetectorRef` and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: You have a typo in your ts keyColmuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try making the below change, which creates a new reference to the array which might cause the reload of the grid.

```
...
).subscribe({
      next: (value: any) => {
        console.log('value', value)
        this.keyData.push({
          active: 1,
          api_set_key: value.result.api_set_key,
          description: "",
          key_id: newKeyId,
        })
        this.keyData = [...this.keyData]; // <-- changed here!
        // A new row is being inserted here but this is not displayed in the UI until I refresh the page.
        this.keyTable.renderRows();
        console.log('this.keyData', this.keyData)
      },
      error: err => {
        console.error('Error:', err)
      },
    })
...
```

Comment: Ok this is an improvement!  This seems to work but only after I click the button more than once. Do you have any idea why this would only update the UI on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th... click but not on the 1st? Thank you.

Comment: Also, could you explain why creating a new array reference would cause the grid to reload whereas a regular mutation might not?

Comment: @Jerome Because arrays are stored by reference ( location in memory) so when you push to an array the reference does not change, but when you do `this.keyData = [...this.keyData];` a new reference to the array is created, which lets angular know that the input has changed and that we need to rerender the view!

Comment: Wouldn't this.keyTable.renderRows(); tell angular to rerender the array regardless of whether it thinks that the input has changed?

Comment: @Jerome Ideally it should work for all clicks, maybe try removing `this.keyTable.renderRows();` or please provide a stackblitz for further debugging

Comment: @Jerome I think it doesnt work for array addition/deletion so you could try this method, in then end whatever works use it!